# Why are object keys converted to "[object Object]"?

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
var a = {},
    b = {key:'b'},
    c = {key:'c'};

a[b] = 111;
a[c] = 222;

console.log(a[b]);
```

Outputs: "222" (not "111").

Explanation:

> `b` and `c` will both be converted to "[object Object]"

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: Thanks for al the answers. I finally understand why. There are three types of object: Object, Array, Date. So, "[object Object]" just means that it is an "object", and its type is "Object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are referring to objects `a` and `b`, but instead of returning you a whole object with its keys and values it instead returns you a string - that says `[object...` - it is an object `...Object]` - type of Object. It could be `[object Function]`, `[object Number]` etc...
So here you are getting two times `[object Object]`, so you are overwriting the key.

If you would write:

```
a[c] = 222;
a[b] = 111;
```

The output would be: `111`

Comment: Could you give an example when we use [object Function] or [object Number]? Thanks Ramziddin.

Comment: var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

Comment: toString.call(123);
toString.call(alert);

Comment: It's mostly used to get type of an object.
function type(obj) {
   return toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
}

Comment: Here's the full code:
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
var isArr = Array.isArray || function isArrayPollyfil(obj) { return toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1) == "Array"; };
function getType(obj) {
   return isArr(obj) ? "array" : typeof obj;
}

Comment: But it's actually just a way of showing you what type of object is it. (Though JavaScript is not a full OOP, I prefer Ruby)

Answer (score 3):

`[object Object]` is just the string representation of an object -- that is, the result of calling `b.toString()` or `c.toString()`.

Object keys are *always* strings, so when you say:

```
a[b]
```

JS will find the string representation of `b` (`[object Object]`), and use that. Same with `c`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Object` as key - `Object` (for example `b`) is converted to `String` (with `toString` method. keys are always converted to strings) and then you will have only one key in object `a` - it will be `[object Object]`,

```
a['[object Object]'] = 111;
a['[object Object]'] = 222;
```

You should set unique keys, like this

```js
var a = {};
var b ={key:'b'};
var c ={key:'c'};

a[b.key] = 111;
a[c.key] = 222;

console.log(a.b);
console.log(a.c);
```